# Scala - flatMap

Tags: scala

I am new to programming and was wondering if anyone can please help me out with this simple problem which is slightly confusing for me.

**Code:**

```
(1 to 3).toList.flatMap(i => (1 to i).map(j => i * j))
```

I don't understand int his part `flatMap(i => (1 to i)` <-- i is not assigned so what pattern does it get mapped in and why?

Also same thing with `(j => i * j)` how do we know what j is? there is no value for j.

I tried to figure out what pattern it makes:
`1,1,2,1,2,3` <-- don't understand why it creates this pattern?

I hope i am making sense.

Thanks,

Comment: Just one question - are you sure that scala is the best language to start learning programming?

Comment: @DmitryReutov yes, totally. Is actually the best mainstream language to learn how to program IMHO. Especially better than the common suggestion of using **Javascript** and **Python**, because those languages hide complexities important in the learning process like the existence of types. - Take a look to [this](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLJGDHERh23x-YBJ8LmYU_IGBFflvsKfLu).

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez, as a person who learnt programming in 80-s via dos basic i beg to disagree, but okay...I think it is okay to hide complexities for beginner otherwise too much complexities

Comment: @DmitryReutov absolutely, I expressed my self wrongly. It is ok to avoid accidental complexity when teaching, for example, I love that you can write a _"hello world"_ in the REPL or in a script file _(of **Scala**, **Python** and **JS**)_ without having to introduce a `final static class Main` or a `static void main(args String[]) {`, - But, that is different to believe types does not exist to then 5 weeks later talk about type exceptions but never ever explaining what a type is _(I have been in a lot of programming 101 classes using python recently, and in all happened this)_.

Comment: So, I believe **Scala** is the best language for teaching because it allows you to scale from simple to complex quite easily, which allows you as a teacher to cover concepts as they are needed and forget others when they are only confusing _(e.g. the difference between function and method, or what a class/object is)_. Whereas languages like **Python** and **Javascript** that are simple for experienced developers are really difficult for newcomers _(I mentored a lot of people that was learning to program using python and concepts like variables, order of execution, or cycles  were not clear)_

Answer (score 1):

`i => foo` is a lambda syntax, so this is creating a **function** so here `i` is the input of that function, it doesn't have a value yet, it will have a value when the function is called. This is similar creating a method like `def bar(x: Int): Int = x + 1`, what is the value of `x`? none, it is just a name for the input it will have a value once called.

It may help to understand seeing the more common `for` syntax:

```scala
val result = for {
  i <- (1 to 3).toLis
  j <- 1 to i
} yield i * j
```

This syntax, which is just sugar syntax for your previous code, makes it easier to understand how this executes under the hood.

Anyways, this is a pretty basic question.
I would recommend you to take a look at the [**tour**](https://docs.scala-lang.org/tour/tour-of-scala.html)  and / or other tutorials / books / courses.
And to rather ask this kind of questions in the [**gitter** channel](https://gitter.im/scala/scala) which is more suited for newcomers.